# What is the study of song structure called?

Tags: terminology, ethnomusicology

I'm describing native Hawaiian songs as part of a research project. The songs are sung by a single performer without instruments.

We transcribed the song into stanzas and now see a number of patterns relating to the length of those stanzas (alongside their melodies) and are describing them for a paper.

What is this kind of study called? I can't find any domain known for "song structure"...

Answer (score 4):

Unless the class is intended for a specialized purpose, the study of musical structure is referred to as **Form & Analysis**. Form & Analysis is not relegated solely to song forms, but all types of music.  Other types of analytical approaches to musical form relate to a more specific, almost specialized analysis.  For example, *Small Form Composition*, *Sonata-Allegro Form*, or perhaps analysis of a single composer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the term you're looking for is [`Musical Form`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_form) Excerpt from the wikipedia page:

> The term musical form (or musical architecture) refers to the overall
>   structure or plan of a piece of music, and it describes the layout of
>   a composition as divided into sections.

Here's an [ebook](https://archive.org/details/structurestylest00stei_0) on Musical Form and a physical book on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881338060).

Answer (score 1):

In form and analysis, the technical term for songs that are organized into stanzas (or verses and choruses) is [strophic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophic_form). Your songs may be in a type of strophic form.

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophic_form):

> *Strophic form* is the term applied to songs in which all verses or stanzas of the text are sung to the same music. The opposite of
>   strophic form, with new music written for every stanza, is called
>   *through-composed*.

Answer (score 0):

How about [**morphology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology) ?

> Morphology, from the Greek and meaning "study of shape".

This is the word we use in Greek when we study song structures. For instance, using a morphology book, you could study the structures used in a Fugue, a sonata etc.

Comment: The link doesn't have a music morphology section

Answer (score -1):

*Musicology*, analysis of music.  In this case, you might want to say *ethnomusicology*.

Comment: "Ethnomusicology" typically focuses on *non-musical* aspects of music that influence the music. The OP is looking for song structure, specifically.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - Do you like this better?  Musicology of traditional Hawaiian music?

Comment: I cannot tell if you are serious...